# Import file from another application using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I want to develop an iOS application where i want to get any PDF/Doc/XLS file present in my Mail/Safari by using `UIDocumentInteractionController` and finally upload them to my local server.

I can able to upload image file present in my iPhone to my local server.

But my question is, can i able to fetch PDF/Doc/XLS file(present in safari/ Mail application) to my application by using `UIDocumentInteractionController` & upload them to my local server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch documents, you can tell iOS that your app can open PDF/Doc/XLS.
Do this by adding supported filetype to you info.plist:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1

Comment: So that means UIDocumentInteractionController just open the reuired file but not download the required file & thats why we cant upload it

Comment: `UIDocumentInteractionController` is meant te allow your app the let other apps open a document. For example, you app has a PDF then via the `UIDocumentInteractionController` you can let the user select an other app to open the PDF like iBooks. It does not work the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to Import a file from another application using UIDocumentInteractionController in case of an iPad app. All you need to do is in info.plist of you application you need to add supported document formats. Add applicationDidFinshWithLaunchingOptions delegate method to your app in application delegate class in the following manner.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self applicationDidFinishLaunching:application];

    if (launchOptions && [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey])
    {
        NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSURL *url=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
        NSString *sourceFilePath=[url path];        
        NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSData *fileData=[fileManager contentsAtPath:sourceFilePath];
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.pdf"];
        NSString *updatedFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        BOOL hasWrittenSuccessfully = [fileData writeToFile:updatedFilePath atomically:TRUE];   
    }

    return YES;
}
```